# Error When trying to push ssh keys into github from bash script

Tags: linux, bash, github, ssh, terminal

I am working on a script that creates ssh keys and puts them into github using bash. I am running into this error when running this function.. I want a way to generate ssh keys and put them into github from terminal within my script.

```
sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa
KEY=$(sudo cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
echo "Here is your KEY var: ${KEY}"
read -p "GitHub Username: " USERNAME
read -p "Please enter a title for you ssh key: " TITLE
curl --user "\"${USERNAME}"\" -X POST --data '{ "\"title"\": "\"$TITLE"\", "\"key"\": "\"$KEY"\" }' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

Error: {
  "message": "Bad credentials",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}

Comment: Why are you running `ssh-keygen` as root?

Comment: That is a really good question lol

Comment: Repeat after me: `sudo` is not a magic "make everything work" command. For every command that can be written with sudo, there is a better approach without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting too many quotes in the command. The correct code (to a first approximation) would be

```
curl --user "${USERNAME}" -X POST \
     --data "{ \"title\": \"$TITLE\", \"key\": \"$KEY\" }" \
     https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

However this is prone to failure if either `TITLE` or `KEY` contains a character that needs to be escaped to include in JSON. The right way to do this is to generate the JSON with a tool like `jq`, which takes care of any necessary escaping.

```
curl --user "${USERNAME}" -X POST \
     --data "$(jq -n --arg t "$TITLE" --arg k "$KEY" \
                  '{title: $t, key: $k}')" \
     https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

or

```
jq -n --arg t "$TITLE" --arg k "$KEY" '{title: $t, key: $k}' |
  curl --user "$USERNAME" -X POST --data @- https://api.github.com/user/keys
```